# Google Play Services error?

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I got this error randomly (I did not change the line/lines and the did work before this):

```
error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
```

at this line:

```
locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL);
```

(I am using google FusedLocationProviderAPI here)

Why do I get this error and what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I managed to solve this problem. If anyone would have the same error, try this.*

I had a conflict in my `build.gradle(app)` file. I had these two:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

which resulted in a conflict since there are two different versions. I just updated `...services-location:9.4.0` to `...services-location:10.0.1` and problem solved.